# How can I make a list of different datatypes then save to a file c#

Tags: c#, file

I need to get a list with differnt datatypes and save them into a text file. I have made code to get the variables and make a file. I don't know how to make the list, and then save it.

This is my code:

```
//Get name.
Console.Write("Name:");
string name = Console.ReadLine();

//Get age.
Console.Write("Age:");
int age = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

//Get favorite color.
Console.Write("Favorite color:");
string color = Console.ReadLine();

//Get favorite number.
Console.Write("Favorite number:");
int number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

//Save to stats.txt
string path = @"C:\Users\max\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\C#\SaveAndLoad\STATS\stats.txt";
using (FileStream makeFile = File.Create(path));
```

Comment: The easiest way is to use a BinaryWriter or BinaryReader, but you can also simply write out the text representation of each type and parse it when you read it back in, just as you are already doing now with Convert.ToInt16.  You can also use Serialization and Deserialization.

Comment: Tip: `int` is `Int32` not `Int16`. Btw, you may use `int.Parse()` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I save variables to a new text file so that those variables are loaded the next time the program runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278839/how-do-i-save-variables-to-a-new-text-file-so-that-those-variables-are-loaded-th)

Comment: You may mark some answer as accepted in case it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/introducing-xml-serialization).

First, create a class to encapsulate your data:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public string FavoriteColor;
    public int FavoriteNumber;
}
```

Then, an example of writing and reading the file:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Name:");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    //Get age.
    Console.Write("Age:");
    int age = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

    //Get favorite color.
    Console.Write("Favorite color:");
    string color = Console.ReadLine();

    //Get favorite number.
    Console.Write("Favorite number:");
    int number = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

    //Save to stats.txt
    string path = @"C:\Users\max\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\C#\SaveAndLoad\STATS\stats.txt";
    Data data = new Data() { Name = name, Age = age, FavoriteColor = color, FavoriteNumber = number };
    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
        xml.Serialize(fs, data);
    }

    // read from stats.txt into a Data object
    Data data2;
    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Data));
        data2 = xml.Deserialize(fs) as Data;
    }
    // do something with "data2":
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + data2.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Age: " + data2.Age);
    Console.WriteLine("Color: " + data2.FavoriteColor);
    Console.WriteLine("Number: " + data2.FavoriteNumber);

    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Generated XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Name>Mike</Name>
  <Age>47</Age>
  <FavoriteColor>Blue</FavoriteColor>
  <FavoriteNumber>42</FavoriteNumber>
</Data>
```

If you create another class that has `List<Data>` in it, you can use very similar code to serialize that class in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to save it as text, you may use `StreamWriter`.

```cs
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
{
    sw.WriteLine(name);
    sw.WriteLine(age);
    sw.WriteLine(color);
    sw.WriteLine(number);
}
```

It behaves similar to `Console.WriteLine()`.

To read do the same as from `Console`.

```cs
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    name = sr.ReadLine();
    age = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
    color = sr.ReadLine();
    number = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
}
```

Or another version (just for fun) for display file's content.

```cs
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
// you may load it to variables too
name = lines[0];
age = int.Parse(lines[1]);
color = lines[2];
number = int.Parse(lines[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different solutions to do this.

As I can see in your example, it is not necessarily a list, your goal is just to save and read information from a file.

I will illustrate a solution using a class and JSON.

First create a class for your object:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FavoriteColor { get; set; }
    public int FavoriteNumber { get; set; }
}
```

To write:

```
// Create an instance of `Person`
var person = new Person
{
   Name = name,
   Age = age,
   FavoriteColor = favoriteColor,
   FavoriteNumber = favoriteNumber
};

// Serialize this object as a JSON
var serializedPerson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);

// Write in the file
File.WriteAllText(path, serializedPerson);
```

To read:

```
// Reads the file
var serializedPerson = File.ReadAllText(path);

// Deserialize the object 
var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>();
```