# loading from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xmlhelper

i am trying loading and saving data by Robert Harvey code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257193/where-to-store-constant-objects-that-will-be-used-in-my-application?answertab=active#tab-top) topic. i can save.
but load process is not success full.

i have tried :

```
var list = XmlHelper.FromXmlFile<List<Item>>(@"c:\folder\file.xml");
```

i did not find the correct namespase for Item

```
var list = XmlHelper.FromXmlFile<List<Array>>(@"c:\folder\file.xml");
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
var list = XmlHelper.FromXmlFile<List<ArrayList>>(@"c:\folder\file.xml");
{"<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns=''> was not expected."}
var list = XmlHelper.FromXmlFile<List<Double>>(@"c:\folder\file.xml");
{"<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns=''> was not expected."}
```

but all of them have error which listed below them.

i want to retrieve those number in form of arraylist or double[];

the XML content :
[image]

Comment: I don't know about XmlHelper. Look into XDocument instead. XDocument looks simpler in usage to me. Not that I am an expert or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Load the Document:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\somefile.xml");
```

Then you can access the Elements with

```
XElement xe = doc.Element("Name of the Element");
```

If you got more than one Element with the same name you can get them with:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xe = doc.Elements("Name of the Element");
```

You can Access Attributes kind of similar:

```
XAttribute xa = doc.Attribute("Name of the Attribute");
```

and

```
IEnumerable<XAttribute> xa = doc.Attributes("name");
```

don't forget to always do null checks.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

for loading the data from xml file use the below process if you are using c#

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\XML1.xml");
```

Comment: I agree. That's why i suggested XDocument instead in the comment above. With XDocument you can access every XElement and XAttribute that is in the xml file.

Comment: it loads all the xml as a single variable with one node. So how can i access to the numbers.

Comment: it has a value property that its value is type string and added all numbers to gether like this( it is a single string)  : "216.23737589973135209.67775014847356106.6266524689597299.760910704962214302.68822465901223293.86403464104819"

Comment: @majidmobini just go thorugh this document i hope it will help http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=564

Comment: @Neel the problem is here that the xml load as a single element so the code in the document dose not work for it.

Comment: @Majid Mobini: Yeah. That's why its better to use XDocument.Load() instead of XElement. XDocument should contain ALL Elements and Attributes. I am no expert but I'll try to post a short answer.